# Deploy build on iis Asp dot net mvc 5 with angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, angular-routing

I uploaded a build of ASP dot net mvc 5 which is used with Angular 1.8.2 on IIS, when i run the web site, it's give me error.

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.2/$injector/modulerr?p0=myAppDash&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.8.2%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3Dn%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdeshboard%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DWBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1%3A10%3A168%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdeshboard%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DWBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1%3A49%3A468%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdeshboard%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DWBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1%3A47%3A197)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdeshboard%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DWBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1%3A47%3A438)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.invoke%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdeshboard%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DWBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1%3A48%3A16)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdeshboard%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DWBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1%3A46%3A148)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdeshboard%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DWBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1%3A46%3A287%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdeshboard%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DWBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1%3A11%3A76)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdeshboard%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DWBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1%3A46%3A49)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20fb%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fdeshboard%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DWBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1%3A50%3A153)
> at angular?v=WBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1:10:168
> at angular?v=WBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1:46:491
> at r (angular?v=WBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1:11:76)
> at g (angular?v=WBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1:46:49)
> at fb (angular?v=WBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1:50:153)
> at c (angular?v=WBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1:25:57)
> at Wc (angular?v=WBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1:25:370)
> at Ee (angular?v=WBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1:24:45)
> at angular?v=WBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1:354:117
> at HTMLDocument.b (angular?v=WBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1:42:137)

and didn't load the angular,
Please Help me.

I set the base tag

```
<base href="deshboard/" />
```

like this.
I want to load angular in my project.